# How to find the minimum and maximum in a ArrayList<Entry> using Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to find the minimum and the maximum of a

```
ArrayList<Entry>
```

For example my ArrayList looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Entry> test = new ArrayList<Entry>();
test.add(new Entry(20, 0));
test.add(new Entry(5, 0));
test.add(new Entry(15, 0));
```

now I want the minimum(5) and the maximum(20) of this list.

I tried it with:

```
Collections.min(test);
```

But it says:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method min(Collection<? extends T>) of type  Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Entry>). The inferred type Entry is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>

I also tried:

```
test.length()
```

so I could do a for loop. But it also failed with this kind of ArrayList.

Comment: Sort it. Take the first and the last elements, then.

Comment: Use `test.size()` instead of `test.length()`. And don't hesitate to read [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, define a `Comparator<Entry>` which defines an ordering for `Entry`:

```
class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry> {
  @Override public int compare(Entry a, Entry b) {
    // ... whatever logic to compare entries.
    // Must return a negative number if a is "less than" b
    // Must return zero if a is "equal to" b
    // Must return a positive number if a is "greater than" b
  }
}
```

Then just iterate through the list, comparing each element to the current minimum and maximum elements:

```
Comparator<Entry> comparator = new EntryComparator();
Iterator<Entry> it = list.iterator();
Entry min, max;
// Assumes that the list is not empty
// (in which case min and max aren't defined anyway).

// Any element in the list is an upper bound on the min
// and a lower bound on the max.
min = max = it.next();

// Go through all of the other elements...
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Entry next = it.next();
  if (comparator.compare(next, min) < 0) {
    // Next is "less than" the current min, so take it as the new min.
    min = next;
  }
  if (comparator.compare(next, max) > 0) {
    // Next is "greater than" the current max, so take it as the new max.
    max = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a custom comparator and explicit iterating through collection and calling it? At first, you're having tough time trying not to mess all these -1, 0 and 1, and then... you're doing a reverse conversion from -1,0,1 to "smaller" or "larger" relations. Isn't it better to just call `Collections.max(list, comparator)` and `Collections.max(list, comparator)`?

Comment: @VladimirS. (I'm guessing you mean `min` and `max`) Well, sure you can. This solution is a) more flexible, in that it works on `Iterable` as well as `Collection`; b) potentially more efficient since it only iterates once; c) more illustrative, since it shows how to actually implement it without using library methods. <shrug> YMMV :) You are right that using `Collections` methods would be "better", if conciseness is your metric.

Comment: I tried to implement the Class EntryComparator but I can't use the less than and greater than operators in combination with a Entry.


`public class  EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry a, Entry b) {
  
  if(a == b){    
   return 0;
  }
  else if(a < b){
   return -1;
  }
  else if(a > b){
   return 1;
  }
  else{
   return 0;
  }  
  
   }
 }`

Comment: @roux. You can only compare primitive values with `<`, `>` etc. If you could write comparisons like this, you'd have no need for the comparator :) Your code should look more like `if (a.getField() == b.getField()) { return 0; } ...` Please add the definition of `Entry` to the question, then I can suggest an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry` has to implement the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and provide an implementation for `compare(T o1, T o2)`.

`compare`  returns `0` if `o1` and `o2` are equals, a positive value if o1 is less then o2, a negative value otherwise

Comment: It is not usual for a class to implement `Comparator` for itself; it might implement `Comparable`, however, if there is a natural ordering for elements of that class.